# What am I missing in equation alignment with multicols?

Tags: equations, lncs

I know there are questions related to this one, but I cannot get all to work in this case.

Code:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \noindent
        \begin{equation}
                  Precision = \frac{TP}{TP + FP} \label{evaluation1}
        \end{equation} \break
         \begin{equation}
      Recall = \frac{TP}{TP + FN}  \label{evaluation2}
        \end{equation} \break
        \begin{equation}
            F_1 =  2  \cdot \frac{precision \cdot recall}{ precision + recall}  \label{evaluation3}
        \end{equation}
    \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT**

I want to set eqaution 1 & 2 on first row. Then equation 3 on second row, like:

```
equation 1           equation 2  

equation 3
```

Comment: Please tell us what kind of layout you're trying to achieve. (So far, you've mostly shown us what you do not want to achieve.)

Comment: @Mico question editted to add detail about intended layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\columbreak` to switch over to the right column, and separate your construction into two `multicols`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \noindent
  \begin{equation}
    \mathrm{precision} = \frac{TP}{TP + FP}
  \end{equation} \columnbreak
  \begin{equation}
    \mathrm{recall} = \frac{TP}{TP + FN}
  \end{equation}
\end{multicols}

\vspace{\dimexpr-\abovedisplayskip-\belowdisplayskip}% Adjust as needed

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{equation}
    F_1 = 2 \cdot \frac{\mathrm{precision} \cdot \mathrm{recall}}{ \mathrm{precision} + \mathrm{recall} }
  \end{equation}
\end{multicols}

\lipsum[4-6]

\end{document}
```

Depending on the equation contents, you may want to adjust the spacing between the `multicols`.

Comment: Thank you. How can the `\vspace` be adjusted in this case?

Comment: @AminaUmar: I've reduced it by a combination of `\belowdisplayskip` (inserted after the `equation`s in the first `multicols`) and `\abovedisplayskip`(inserted before the `equation` in the second `multicols`). You can add more negative space using `\vspace{\dimexpr-\abovedisplayskip-\belowdisplayskip-2ex}`, where you change `2ex` to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Don't tell anybody I'm using `$$`. Well, there *are* cases where it comes handy.

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\newenvironment{doubleequations}{%
  $$
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth}p{0.5\textwidth}}%
}{\end{tabular}$$}

\begin{document}

text before the equation
text before the equation
text before the equation
text before the equation
\begin{doubleequations}
  \begin{equation}\label{evaluation1}
  \mathrm{Precision} = \frac{\mathrm{TP}}{\mathrm{TP} + \mathrm{FP}}
  \end{equation}
&
  \begin{equation}\label{evaluation2}
  \mathrm{Recall} = \frac{\mathrm{TP}}{\mathrm{TP} + \mathrm{FN}}
  \end{equation}
\\[-2ex]
  \begin{equation}\label{evaluation3}
  F_1 = 2\cdot \frac{\mathrm{Precision} \cdot \mathrm{Recall}}
                    {\mathrm{Precision} + \mathrm{Recall}}
  \end{equation}
\end{doubleequations}
text after the equation
text after the equation
text after the equation
text after the equation

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't write “words” in math mode without segregating them in `\mathrm` (or `\mathit`, if you so prefer).

Adjust the `[-2ex]` spacing to suit yourself.

Why `$$` and not `multicols`? Because this will not allow page breaks before the display.